# Email Doctype in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

do you know why Salesforce Marketing Cloud recommend to use HTML 4.01 Transitional as a DOCTYPE. It is implemented in their default email templates in Email Studio. However, more recommended doctype for emails nowadays is XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Are there any reasons for that?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ignoring the standard templates altogether. I am yet to see an implementation which is making use of these. Normally, I would have new set of templates and content blocks built according to latest standards, and tested across recent email clients. For this, you can utilise e.g. Litmus.

My best guess is, that the standard templates in SFMC have not been updated for at least 8 years.